# Interactive Plot of Pandas Data-frame Color coding based on a group from a Column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, d3.js, plotly, bokeh

I have an example pandas dataframe as follows:

```
      day  id     cnt
      2   catx     4
      2   kagm     3
      2   dyrt     5
      3   catx     3
      3   kagm     3
      3   dyrt     4
      5   catx     2
      5   kagm     2
      5   dyrt     2
```

**I want to plot the scatter data cnt (y) vs day(x), where the points will be labeled (colored/legend) based on the id column**.

Now this is pretty simple in seaborn/matplotlib which I know can be plotted and the plot can be saved to a file.

***However, I am looking to have an interactive plot using plotly/bokeh/d3/mp3ld*** etc and finally, put that plot into an url (of my choice or maybe an account based as in plotly). My goal is also to have hover function, which will show me the value of the points when I take the cursor over a specific cursor point.

**I have tried bokeh/plotly with cufflinks using ColumnDataSource** and everything to try out to get the plots. However, have failed to get anything which I am looking for. Can I get some help in this direction from the experts? Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: do you have any other requirements when these are solved?

Comment: Thank you. No I just want to post them to my desired url with the interacting features along with the color coding. No further processing needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code plots the data the way you requested. I created a new dataframe for every category in your dataframe so the interactive legend also works. An array with hex color strings is generated with the length of the number of unique categories and added to the dataframe to give every category it's own color.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.palettes import all_palettes
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show

data = {'day': [2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5], 'id': ['catx', 'kagm', 'dyrt', 'catx', 'kagm', 'dyrt', 'catx', 'kagm', 'dyrt'], 'cnt': [4, 3, 5, 3, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2]}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

output_file('plot.html')
tooltips = [
    ("day", "@day"),
    ("id", "@$name"),
    ("count", "@cnt")]
p = figure(tooltips=tooltips, plot_width=800, plot_height=800)

sources = []
colors = all_palettes['Viridis'][len(set(df['id'].tolist()))]
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None #Supress false positive warning
for ID, color in zip(set(df['id'].tolist()), colors):
    dfSubset = df.loc[df['id'] == ID]
    dfSubset['color'] = color
    sources.append(ColumnDataSource(dfSubset))
    p.circle(x = 'day', y = 'cnt', legend = 'id', color = 'color', name = 'id', alpha = 0.5, size = 15, source = sources[-1])

p.legend.click_policy="hide"

show(p)
```

[image: plot]